# DRBD Not syncing between my nodes

Tags: linux, mysql, replication, drbd

Some version info:

```
Operating system is Ubuntu 11.10, on EC2, kernel is 3.0.0-16-virtual and the application info is:

Version: 8.3.11 (api:88)
GIT-hash: 0de839cee13a4160eed6037c4bddd066645e23c5 build by buildd@allspice, 2011-07-05 19:51:07
```

Getting some strange errors in dmesg (seen below) as well, there is no replication happening.  I have made my first node primary and its showing:

```
drbd driver loaded OK; device status:
version: 8.3.11 (api:88/proto:86-96)
srcversion: DA5A13F16DE6553FC7CE9B2 
m:res  cs          ro               ds                 p       mounted  fstype
0:r0   StandAlone  Primary/Unknown  UpToDate/DUnknown  r----s  ext3
```

my secondary node is showing:

```
drbd driver loaded OK; device status:
version: 8.3.11 (api:88/proto:86-96)
srcversion: DA5A13F16DE6553FC7CE9B2 
m:res  cs          ro                 ds                     p       mounted  fstype
0:r0   StandAlone  Secondary/Unknown  Inconsistent/DUnknown  r----s
```

Showing /proc/drbd on the master shows:

```
version: 8.3.11 (api:88/proto:86-96)
srcversion: DA5A13F16DE6553FC7CE9B2 
 0: cs:StandAlone ro:Primary/Unknown ds:UpToDate/DUnknown   r----s
    ns:0 nr:0 dw:4 dr:1073 al:0 bm:0 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:f oos:262135964
```

Showing /proc/drbd on the slave shows that there is nothing being transfered...

```
version: 8.3.11 (api:88/proto:86-96)
srcversion: DA5A13F16DE6553FC7CE9B2 
 0: cs:StandAlone ro:Secondary/Unknown ds:Inconsistent/DUnknown   r----s
    ns:0 nr:0 dw:0 dr:0 al:0 bm:0 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:f oos:262135964
```

Here is my config...

```
resource r0 {
    protocol C;
    startup {
        wfc-timeout  15;
        degr-wfc-timeout 60;
    }
    net {
        cram-hmac-alg sha1;
        shared-secret "test123;
    }
    on drbd01 {
        device /dev/drbd0;
        disk /dev/xvdm;
        address 23.XX.XX.XX:7788; # blocked out ip
        meta-disk internal;
    }
    on drbd02 {
        device /dev/drbd0;
        disk /dev/xvdm;
        address 184.XX.XX.XX:7788; #blocked out ip
        meta-disk internal;
    }
}
```

I have run the following on the master:

```
sudo drbdadm -- --overwrite-data-of-peer primary all
```

There is no firewall between the systems.

Here is the dmesg with some errors:

```
[2285172.969955] drbd: initialized. Version: 8.3.11 (api:88/proto:86-96)
[2285172.969960] drbd: srcversion: DA5A13F16DE6553FC7CE9B2 
[2285172.969962] drbd: registered as block device major 147
[2285172.969965] drbd: minor_table @ 0xffff88000276ea00
[2285173.000952] block drbd0: Starting worker thread (from drbdsetup [1300])
[2285173.003971] block drbd0: disk( Diskless -> Attaching ) 
[2285173.006150] block drbd0: No usable activity log found.
[2285173.006154] block drbd0: Method to ensure write ordering: flush
[2285173.006158] block drbd0: max BIO size = 4096
[2285173.006165] block drbd0: drbd_bm_resize called with capacity == 524271928
[2285173.008512] block drbd0: resync bitmap: bits=65533991 words=1023969 pages=2000
[2285173.008518] block drbd0: size = 250 GB (262135964 KB)
[2285173.079566] block drbd0: bitmap READ of 2000 pages took 17 jiffies
[2285173.081189] block drbd0: recounting of set bits took additional 1 jiffies
[2285173.081194] block drbd0: 250 GB (65533991 bits) marked out-of-sync by on disk bit-map.
[2285173.081203] block drbd0: Suspended AL updates
[2285173.081210] block drbd0: disk( Attaching -> UpToDate ) 
[2285173.081214] block drbd0: attached to UUIDs 1C1291D39584C1D1:0000000000000004:0000000000000000:0000000000000000
[2285173.095016] block drbd0: conn( StandAlone -> Unconnected ) 
[2285173.095046] block drbd0: Starting receiver thread (from drbd0_worker [1301])
[2285173.099297] block drbd0: receiver (re)started
[2285173.099304] block drbd0: conn( Unconnected -> WFConnection ) 
[2285173.099330] block drbd0: bind before connect failed, err = -99
[2285173.099346] block drbd0: conn( WFConnection -> Disconnecting ) 
[2285173.295788] block drbd0: Discarding network configuration.
[2285173.295815] block drbd0: Connection closed
[2285173.295826] block drbd0: conn( Disconnecting -> StandAlone ) 
[2285173.295840] block drbd0: receiver terminated
[2285173.295844] block drbd0: Terminating drbd0_receiver
```

Edit:

Reading some other similar issues, it was suggested to do a 'drbdadm dump all', so I figured it couldn't hurt.

```
ubuntu@drbd01:~$ drbdadm dump all
/etc/drbd.conf:19: in resource r0, on drbd01:
    IP 23.XX.XX.XX not found on this host.
```

and on slave:

```
root@drbd02:~# drbdadm dump all
/etc/drbd.conf:25: in resource r0, on drbd02:
    IP 184.XX.XX.XX not found on this host.
```

Strange it doesn't find its own ip, however, this is an Amazon EC2 system using an elastic IP... here are my ipconfigs for both...

master:

```
ubuntu@drbd01:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 22:00:0a:1c:27:11  
          inet addr:10.28.39.17  Bcast:10.28.39.63  Mask:255.255.255.192
          inet6 addr: fe80::2000:aff:fe1c:2711/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1569 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1169 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:124409 (124.4 KB)  TX bytes:213601 (213.6 KB)
          Interrupt:26 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

slave:

```
root@drbd02:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 12:31:3f:00:14:9d  
          inet addr:10.160.27.107  Bcast:10.160.27.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1031:3fff:fe00:149d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:915 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:774 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:75381 (75.3 KB)  TX bytes:109673 (109.6 KB)
          Interrupt:26 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Comment: I'm trying to work out why you'd run single-primary DRBD on EC2.  Why not just use EBS volumes and attach them where you need them to go?

Comment: We're just experimenting currently (between West1 and East1), once we get this working, we want to go across geographical zones- we've seen many cases where entire  regions become inaccessible (3 times albeit very short periods).  From what I can see, we are having issues with Elastic IP's - there is no internet interface, and looks like DRBD doesn't like it.

Comment: Yeah, DRBD isn't going to work well for you across regions, the latency will kill you.  You really need the paid drbdproxy for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You actually did not need to run `sudo drbdadm -- --overwrite-data-of-peer primary all`

AS long as /dev/drbdYou should have done the following

Step01) `sudo service mysql stop` on DRBD Primary so additional changes are not piled for DRBD to sync

Step02) `sudo drbdadm connect all` on DRBD Secondary

Step03) `sudo cat /proc/drbd` on DRBD Secondary to make sure the connection stats is `WFConnection`

Step04) `sudo drbdadm connect all` on DRBD Primary

Step05) `sudo cat /proc/drbd` on DRBD Primary to make sure the connection state is `SyncTarget`.

Step06) `sudo service mysql start` on DRBD Primary so MySQL can get back up. The DRBD sync will continue. You do not have to wait for DRBD to be fully sync'd in Step 05 to re-enable MySQL.

**CAVEAT #1**

DRBD should not be used over a geographic distance. It kinda works with setups that have DRBD pairs connect via CrossOver Cables over 192.168.x.x.. or other pure LAN.

**CAVEAT #2**

DRBD should not be used at all. Even the most recent V9 goes into “split brain” mode easily.

Answer (score 3):

Try following:

On **primary** node

```
drbdadm connect all
```

On **secondary** node

```
drbdadm -- --discard-my-data connect all
```